# How to unit test google cloud storage in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing an appengine app in Go that uses [Google cloud storage](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/storage).

For example, my "reading" code looks like:

```
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer func() {
    if err := client.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}()
r, err := client.Bucket(BucketName).Object(id).NewReader(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer r.Close()
return ioutil.ReadAll(r)
```

... where `ctx` is a context from appengine.

When I run this code in a unit test (using `aetest`), it actually sends requests to my cloud storage; I'd like to run this hermetically instead, similar to how `aetest` allows fake datastore calls.

(Possibly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613897/unit-testing-googles-cloud-storage-api), but it deals with python, and the linked [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/issues/21) indicates it's solved in a python-specific way).

How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/mock ?

Comment: @SachinNambiarNalavattanon I'm looking for a fake storage; are you suggesting that I mock it and implement a fake myself?

Comment: If you end up calling an external resources you are not doing unit test. You have a function that get text and find most used words. This function get a bytes buffer and return slice of results. In test you take a string and turn it to a bytes buffer and send it to the function and in production you read from GCS turn the file to bytes buffer and send it to the function.

Answer (score 7):

One approach, also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167970/mock-functions-in-go) is to allow your GCS client to have its downloader swapped out for a stub while unit testing. First, define an interface that matches how you use the Google Cloud Storage library, and then reimplement it with fake data in your unit tests.

Something like this:

```
type StorageClient interface {
  Bucket(string) Bucket  // ... and so on, matching the Google library
}

type Storage struct {
  client StorageClient
}

// New creates a new Storage client
// This is the function you use in your app
func New() Storage {
  return NewWithClient(&realGoogleClient{}) // provide real implementation here as argument
}

// NewWithClient creates a new Storage client with a custom implementation
// This is the function you use in your unit tests
func NewWithClient(client StorageClient) {
  return Storage{
    client: client,
  }
}
```

It can be a lot of boilerplate to mock entire 3rd party APIs, so maybe you'll be able to make it easier by generating some of those mocks with [golang/mock](https://github.com/golang/mock) or [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery).

Answer (score 7):

I have done something like this...

Since storage client is sending HTTPS request so I mocked the HTTPS server using `httptest`

```
func Test_StorageClient(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name        string
        mockHandler func() http.Handler
        wantErr     bool
    }{
        {
            name: "test1",
            mockHandler: func() http.Handler {
                return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                    w.Write([]byte("22\n96\n120\n"))
                    return
                })
            },
            wantErr: false,
        },
        {
            name: "test2 ",
            mockHandler: func() http.Handler {
                return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
                    return
                })
            },
            wantErr: true,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            serv := httptest.NewTLSServer(tt.mockHandler())
            httpclient := http.Client{
                Transport: &http.Transport{
                    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
                    },
                },
            }
            client, _ := storage.NewClient(context.Background(), option.WithEndpoint(serv.URL), option.WithoutAuthentication(), option.WithHTTPClient(&httpclient))
            got, err := readFileFromGCS(client)
            if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
                return
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage on the Python Development server is emulated using local files with the Blobstore service, which is why the solution of using a Blobstore stub with testbed (also Python-specific) worked. However there is no such local emulation for Cloud Storage on the Go runtime.

As Sachin suggested, the way to unit test Cloud Storage is to use a mock. This is the way it's done internally and on other runtimes, such as [node](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1032).

Answer (score -2):

I would advice you reduce the mocks as much as possible you might need to use an hermetic approach to make it almost similar to the real thing .
https://testing.googleblog.com/2012/10/hermetic-servers.html